# Calling free() causes my program to crash

Tags: c, crash, printf, malloc, free

I'm having a really weird issue where trying to call free on an allocated piece of memory causes my program to crash.

Here's the relevant code:

```
int i, count;
char *specifier;
char aisle[1];
count = 0;

/*Find name of the new item and assign to the name field of new_node...*/
for (i = 0; input[i] != ','; i++){
    count++;
}
specifier = (char*)malloc((count+1)*sizeof(char));
if (specifier == NULL){
    printf("Out of memory. Shutting down.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for (i = 0; input[i] != ','; i++){
    specifier[i] = input[i];
}
specifier[count+1] = '\0';
new_node->name = specifier;
printf("%s\n", new_node->name);
free(specifier); /*PROGRAM CRASHES HERE*/
printf("boom\n");
specifier = NULL;
/*Function continues here*/
```

this is my structure that is used for new_node:

```
/*Outline for the stock levels system...*/
typedef struct item item_t;
struct item{
    char *name;
    char *aisle;
    item_t *left;
    item_t *right;
 };
```

When I run the program, that first printf prints correctly, but the second doesn't. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: How did you allocate `new_node`?

Comment: @timrau new_node is part of a binary search tree, and is allocated in a different function. (`*new_node` is passed into my function above as an argument)

Comment: You didn't include this declaration but, if `new_node->name` is not a pointer, then `new_node->name = specifier;` is going to be problematic as you will be losing a pointer to previously allocated memory.

Comment: @pedwards I've added my structure type. You can see that new_node->name will be of type char.

Comment: The key question is what is `new_node`?  This should be defined as `struct item *new_node` in order to use the `->`.  If this is the case, then you must allocate an instance of `struct item` first or you are scribbling.  Please include your definition for `new_node`...  not the struct.

Comment: @pedwards `item_t *new_node = (item_t*)malloc(sizeof(item_t));` and then `*new_node` is passed into the function that I've described above.

Comment: This is good.  See Answer below...

Comment: OT: Why do you even have an array --> `char aisle[1];`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You allocate space for `count + 1` elements ...

```
specifier = (char*) malloc ( (count+1) * sizeof(char));
```

And then go one past your array (undefined behavior):

```
specifier[count + 1] = '\0';
```