# Call to malloc() causes unexplicable program crash

Tags: c, string

I'm having an issue where a call I'm making to `malloc()` causes my program to crash. Here's the code:

```
void update_item(char *input, item_t *new_node){
    int i, count, shelf, weight, price, quantity;
    char *name;
    char *specifier;
    char aisle[1];
    count = 0;

    /*Find name of the new item and assign to the name field of    new_node...*/
    for (i = 0; input[i] != ','; i++){
        count++;
    }
    name = (char*)malloc((count+1)*sizeof(char));
    if (name == NULL){
        printf("Out of memory. Shutting down.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; input[i] != ','; i++){
        name[i] = input[i];
    }
    name[count+1] = '\0';
    new_node->name = name;
    printf("%s\n", new_node->name);

    /*Find aisle specifier and assign it to aisle field of new_node...*/
    i++;
    aisle[0] = input[i];
    aisle[1] = '\0';
    new_node->aisle = aisle;
    printf("%s\n", new_node->aisle);

    for(i = i+2, count = 0; input[i] != ','; i++){
        count++;
    }
    specifier = (char*)malloc(count*sizeof(char)); /*PROGRAM CRASHES HERE*/
    if (specifier == NULL){
        printf("Out of memory. Shutting down.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("boom\n");
```

I'm utterly stumped. There's two identical calls to `malloc()` but for some reason the second fails every single time while the first one always is a success.

Comment: Describe "program crashes"? Does it print `"Out of memory. Shutting down."`? Do you have an error message? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: No it doesn't print my error message. Windows takes over and forces the program to close.

Comment: Also warning: when calling `sizeof` in `malloc` (and the like) [you should always write it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17258659/1151654) as `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * ...);` instead of `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptrtype*) * ...);`. And you [should not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the return of malloc.

Comment: Are you sure `input[i]` will eventually reach a coma?

Comment: What about all my other questions? Have you tried simply using a debugger?

Comment: If you had used a debugger, you'd realize that the program doesn't crash at the malloc call, but later.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30191540/3049655) once again, please

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>` to use malloc properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Point 1**

```
 for (i = 0; input[i] != ','; i++){
```

is unsafe. if your `input` does not contain `,` you'll be overrunning memory. Instead use something like

```
 int len = strlen(input);
 for (i = 0; (input[i] != ',') && len ; i++, len--){
```

**Point 2**

in `C`, we have `0` based index. so, for an allocation like,

```
name = malloc(count+1);
```

later, doing

```
name[count+1] = '\0';
```

is again meory overrun, which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Note:

1. Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. `sizeof(char)` is guranteed to be `1` in `C`, you can get rid of that.

**Point 3**

as per your code, `aisle` is defined as

```
char aisle[1];
```

however, later, you used

```
aisle[0] = input[i];
aisle[1] = '\0';
```

which is again memory overrun and UB. Change you `aisle` to

```
char aisle[2] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name[count+1] = '\0';
```

Above line should be

```
name[count] = '\0'; //one item less
```

Your code will cause write to 1 additional memory location which is not allocated by you.

---

There also problem with these lines ...

```
aisle[0] = input[i]; 
aisle[1] = '\0';    // aisle has only 1 char not 2
new_node->aisle = aisle; // you are storing reference of local  
                         // variable, not good.
```